# How to get apps names and developer details from play store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Is there a way to get google play apps names and developer details by criteria?

Is there some api for accessing public play store data?

Answer (score 0):

Google does not provide an official API for getting the data, but you can take a look at these open source projects

https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics/wiki/Developer-Console-Protocol
https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/
https://github.com/chadrem/market_bot